# How people perceive themselves?

Tags: data-request

since i'm not sure if my question is as specific as expected by Stack* audience, I would like to explain a little what I would like to get.

I'm looking for a database, dataset or some data source where I can find information about how people feel about themselves.

Suppose that we are dealing with some "how I feel about *" test where there are questions which answer falls in a range between "not so much" to "yes, indeed".

Imagine questions like:

- "Do you think you're liberal?"
- "Are you fine with meeting people from different countries?"
- "Do you think you can manage unexpected situations?"
- "Do you value the support of your family?"

and so on...

Suggestions?

Comment: Polling companies like gallup.com have this data and release it in various forms: https://news.gallup.com/topic/report.aspx might be a useful starting point. Of course, not all of their data is free, but quite a bit of it is. I signed up for their newsletter and they send me vaguely interesting stats on a weekly basis.

Comment: that's interesting, i haven't thought of polling companies released reports. i'll look into it!